# Another IE8 image load issue

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer-8, onload-event

I've searched through different sites and can't quite figure out where I've gone wrong. This works in the major browsers, but not in IE7 or IE8. My issue is that the source of the event is null once the image is loaded. You'll see that printed out on the page (I have a div where I'm sending some text). Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var panorama = new Object();
    var mainContainer;
    var panoHolder;
    var panoCanvas;
    //once document is loaded starts website
    AttachEvent(window, 'load', eventWindowLoaded);

    // logic to attach the event correctly in IE
    function AttachEvent(element, type, handler) {
        if (element.addEventListener) {
            element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
        }else if (element.attachEvent) {
            element.attachEvent('on' + type, handler)
        } else {
            element['on' + type] = handler;
        }
    }

    function eventWindowLoaded() {
        panorama.totalpanels = 6;
        panorama.sourceLocation = "my_files/images/";
        panorama.width = 3200;
        panorama.height = 964;
        panorama.thumbnails = new Object();
        panorama.thumbnails.images = new Array(panorama.totalpanels);
        panorama.thumbnails.imageWidths = new Array();
        panorama.thumbnails.imageHeight = 0;

        //sets attributes of container objects
        mainContainer = document.createElement("div");
        mainContainer.id = "container";
        mainContainer.style.width = "1010px";
        mainContainer.style.height = panorama.height + "px";

        obj("mainelement").appendChild(mainContainer);

        panoHolder = document.createElement("div");
        panoHolder.id = "animationholder";
        panoHolder.style.width = panorama.width + "px";
        panoHolder.style.height = panorama.height + "px";
        panoHolder.style.left = '0px';
        panoHolder.style.top = "0px";
        mainContainer.appendChild(panoHolder);

        panoCanvas = document.createElement("div");
        panoCanvas.id = "room";
        panoCanvas.width = panorama.width;
        panoCanvas.height = panorama.height;
        panoHolder.appendChild(panoCanvas);

        for(var i = 1; i <= panorama.totalpanels; i++) {
            panorama.thumbnails.images[i - 1] = new Image();
            AttachEvent(panorama.thumbnails.images[i - 1], 'load'preloadThumbnails);
            panorama.thumbnails.images[i - 1].src = panorama.sourceLocation + "TC_tile_thumb" + i + ".jpg";
            panorama.thumbnails.images[i - 1].id = i - 1;
        }
    }

    function preloadThumbnails(e) {
        panorama.thumbnails.loaded++;
        //adds width and height attributes to panorama.thumbnails.imageWidths array
        try {
            panorama.thumbnails.imageWidths.push(e.currentTarget ? e.currentTarget.width : window.event.srcElement.width);
            panorama.thumbnails.imageHeight = e.currentTarget.height;
            panoCanvas.appendChild(e.currentTarget);
        }
        catch (ee) {
            var targ;
            if (!e) var e = window.event;
            if (e.currentTarget) targ = e.currentTarget;
            else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
            t('<br /> error: ' + ee + '<br /> event: ' + e + '<br /> target: ' + targ + '<br />' + e[0], true);
        }

        if (panorama.thumbnails.loaded >= panorama.totalpanels) {
            e.currentTarget.removeEventListener('load', preloadThumbnails , false);
            startFullRezPreload();
        }   
    }
    //returns an object reference
    function obj(element) {
        return document.getElementById(element);
    }

    function t(message, addTo) {
        if (addTo) {
            obj("test").innerHTML += message;
        }
        else {
            obj("test").innerHTML = message;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body id="mainelement">
<div id="test">Test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer (old versions) didn't pass an event object as a parameter. It's stored instead in a global (window) property called "event".

The traditional approach was to do something like this at the top of the event handler:

```
    function preloadThumbnails(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
```

Comment: I moved this line from my catch to be the first line:
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
I still get this on when I trace out, though:

error: TypeError: Unable to get property 'width' of undefined or null reference
event: [object Event]
target: undefined

Comment: Don't redeclare "e" with `var` there. Internet Explorer "event" objects are different than those in other browsers; [check the MSDN documentation for details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863.aspx)  In particular, it's not "target", it's "srcElement".

Comment: Yeah, i recoded the 1st part of the function with the same results (targ == null): `function preloadThumbnails(e) { 
  e = e || window.event;
  var targ;
  if (e.currentTarget) targ = e.currentTarget;
  else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;`

Comment: @StephenSynowsky well, perhaps IE simply doesn't populate the "srcElement" property for "load" events on images.

Comment: That's what I'm starting to think. I switched to jQuery and everything worked out! `panorama.thumbnails.images[i - 1] = $('<img />').attr({ 'id':i - 1, 'src':panorama.sourceLocation + "TC_tile_thumb" + i + ".jpg", load:preloadThumbnails }).appendTo($('#room'));`